# How to add accessibility identifier to ios (cordova/webview) in html

Tags: ios, html, cordova, appium, ios-ui-automation

I am doing mobile ios webview app automation using appium.

I am unable to see the id attributes by using appium inspector.some says need to add accessibility id attribute so that appium can inspect that element.

But we know how to add accessibility id for native app's, but please suggest how to add accessibility for webview app(cordova) in html code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know why, but after spending half a day to explore on appium, I found that if you put these two attribute to the element, it can show the accessibility id on apium

```
<div aria-label="<your_accessibility_id>" role="<your_accessibility_id>">
</div>
```

Comment: have you been able to find any official documentation on this from Apple?